# format %f expects argument of type 'float * ' , but argument 2 has type "double" [-Wformat=]

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_NAME 10
#define MAX_PORTFOLIO 1000

typedef struct {
    char nome[MAX_NAME];
    double valor;
    double yield;
} stock_t;

int main(){
    int i,n,k;
    float max = 0;
    stock_t stocks[MAX_PORTFOLIO];

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%s", stocks[i].nome);
        scanf("%f", &stocks[i].valor);
        scanf("%f", &stocks[i].yield);
    }
...
```

When I run this simple code I get the following error:

```
format %f expects argument of type 'float * ' , but argument 2 has type "double" [-Wformat=] [Ln 25, Col 17]
```

How do I fix this? I am yet to learn  most basics of the language as well so please make it simple so I can really understand

Comment: What does your beginners books or tutorials say about `scanf` and the arguments you need to pass? Why do you think the compiler say it expects a `float *`, a *pointer*?

Comment: On a couple of different notes: First don't use `float`, it's almost never needed. Use `double` instead. Secondly don't use floating point types for anything related to money. Floating point types are prone to rounding and other problems that could lead to money being lost or gained unexpectedly. Use *fixed* point types, or integers storing the smallest denomination (like cents for US currency).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I dont know the specifics of each data type yet. anyways thats useful information. thank you. Also I don't quite understand why it keeps showing up the same error when & is and isnt behind the stocks[i].valor line

Comment: That error message doesn't seem to match your code. You provide `double*` while the error mentions `double`. Did you save your code after you added `&`? Even if `double*` is still wrong, you should care to provide correct code and errors.

Comment: Please don't "fix" the code in your question, it makes posted answers (and the question itself) kind of useless. The question no longer have the problem you ask about, and the answers just don't make sense.

Comment: And your original question had `scanf("%d", &n);` which indicates that you know you must use a pointer and the pointer-to operator `&`. Why didn't you use it on the other `scanf` calls?

Answer (score 1):

While scanning the input, scanf needs to store that input data somewhere. To store this input data, scanf needs to know the memory location of a variable. And here comes the ampersand to rescue.

& is also called as address of the operator.
For example, &double_var is the address of double_var:

```
scanf("%lf",&double_var);
```

This question actually appeared because there was a bug in the IDE that wasn't updating the warning in the title. The fix was adding the addresses (&) and changing the type specifiers. (from "%f" to "%lf") and restarting the IDE.

Comment: because I had the correct formatting and it would always show up a warning. Since im using a virtual box I was expecting some weird behaviour anyways